# lib not found: Pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Estou tentando montar um executável, a partir de um código em python pela biblioteca Pyinstaller. Porém ao executar o código por:

```
C:\...>pyinstaller --name Aplicativo Aplicativo.pyw
```

é gerado uma quantidade de uma quantidade grande de .dll que não são localizadas, por exemplo:

```
...
224734 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\scipy\spatial\qhull.cp35-win32.pyd
225035 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\scipy\spatial\qhull.cp35-win32.pyd
225396 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\scipy\spatial\qhull.cp35-win32.pyd
225715 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\scipy\spatial\qhull.cp35-win32.pyd
225995 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\scipy\spatial\qhull.cp35-win32.pyd
226088 WARNING: lib not found: libopenblas.UWVN3XTD2LSS7SFIFK6TIQ5GONFDBJKU.gfortran-win32.dll dependency of C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\scipy\spatial\qhull.cp35-win32.pyd
226394 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\scipy\spatial\qhull.cp35-win32.pyd
226697 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\scipy\spatial\qhull.cp35-win32.pyd
227012 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\scipy\spatial\qhull.cp35-win32.pyd
227317 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\scipy\spatial\ckdtree.cp35-win32.pyd
227609 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\scipy\spatial\ckdtree.cp35-win32.pyd
227933 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\scipy\spatial\ckdtree.cp35-win32.pyd
228598 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\cv2.cp35-win32.pyd
228911 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\cv2.cp35-win32.pyd
229247 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\cv2.cp35-win32.pyd
229568 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\cv2.cp35-win32.pyd
229866 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\cv2.cp35-win32.pyd
230162 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\cv2.cp35-win32.pyd
230443 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\cv2.cp35-win32.pyd
230757 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\cv2.cp35-win32.pyd
231054 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\cv2.cp35-win32.pyd
231355 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\cv2.cp35-win32.pyd
231651 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\cv2.cp35-win32.pyd
231960 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\lxml\etree.cp35-win32.pyd
232257 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\lxml\etree.cp35-win32.pyd
232608 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\lxml\etree.cp35-win32.pyd
232874 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\lxml\etree.cp35-win32.pyd
233168 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\lxml\etree.cp35-win32.pyd
233465 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\lxml\etree.cp35-win32.pyd
233768 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\lxml\etree.cp35-win32.pyd
234018 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\lxml\etree.cp35-win32.pyd
234340 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\lxml\etree.cp35-win32.pyd
234625 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\lxml\etree.cp35-win32.pyd
234922 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\lxml\_elementpath.cp35-win32.pyd
235259 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\QtGui.pyd
235567 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\QtGui.pyd
235886 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\QtCore.pyd
236195 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\QtCore.pyd
236489 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\QtCore.pyd
236778 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\QtCore.pyd
237100 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\QtCore.pyd
238194 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\program files (x86)\python35-32\DLLs\tk86t.dll
238495 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\program files (x86)\python35-32\DLLs\tk86t.dll
238761 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\program files (x86)\python35-32\DLLs\tk86t.dll
239060 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\program files (x86)\python35-32\DLLs\tk86t.dll
239353 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\program files (x86)\python35-32\DLLs\tk86t.dll
239702 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\program files (x86)\python35-32\DLLs\tk86t.dll
239960 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\program files (x86)\python35-32\DLLs\tk86t.dll
240271 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\program files (x86)\python35-32\DLLs\tk86t.dll
240606 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\program files (x86)\python35-32\DLLs\tcl86t.dll
240904 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\program files (x86)\python35-32\DLLs\tcl86t.dll
241200 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\program files (x86)\python35-32\DLLs\tcl86t.dll
241512 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\program files (x86)\python35-32\DLLs\tcl86t.dll
241823 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\program files (x86)\python35-32\DLLs\tcl86t.dll
242163 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\program files (x86)\python35-32\DLLs\tcl86t.dll
242455 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\program files (x86)\python35-32\DLLs\tcl86t.dll
242739 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\program files (x86)\python35-32\DLLs\tcl86t.dll
243020 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\program files (x86)\python35-32\DLLs\tcl86t.dll
243459 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\QtGui4.dll
243773 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\QtGui4.dll
244101 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\QtGui4.dll
244404 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\QtGui4.dll
244724 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\QtGui4.dll
245105 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\QtCore4.dll
245381 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\QtCore4.dll
245665 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\QtCore4.dll
...
```

Ao executar o "Programa", geram essas linhas de erro

```
File "aplicacao.pyw", line 17, in <module>
    from imutils import perspective
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python35-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "imutils\perspective.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python35-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "scipy\spatial\__init__.py", line 95, in <module>
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python35-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 714, in load_module
    module = loader.load_module(fullname)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
[2732] Failed to execute script aplicacao
```

Eu já consegui uma vez criar um executável desse mesmo programa, por essa biblioteca, agora não sei mais o que está acontecendo. Alguém saberia como gerar esse executável? As bibliotecas utilizadas foram: PyQt4;matplotlib;opencv;imutils;docx;numpy;date e math e existem alguns arquivos de imagem e texto.

Comment: Já tentou gerar o executável de um script simples, tipo hello world ?

Comment: Não, mas como eu comentei, eu já consegui gerar esse executável, só que fiz umas modificações simples na inteface, por exemplo: ajuste de botões, ai agora não gera mais.
Mas irei verificar com um script mais simples =)

Comment: Acredito que você também precise instalar o Visual C++.

Comment: olhei agora, o visual C++ já está instalado no meu computador

Comment: Baixei a versão 2017 do Visual C++ e mesmo assim continua dando os mesmos problemas